# Append mode in XlsxWriter corrupting existing file

Tags: openpyxl, xlsxwriter

I am trying to write a dataframe to a new sheet in an existing `.xlsx` workbook using the code below. When I try and manually open the file, I get a message stating an error was found, would I like to try and recover. If I enable Excel to recover the file, the data is there in the expected format in the expected sheet. The issue is that I am not able to append another dataframe/worksheet to the same file before it has been "repaired" by manually opening and selecting to try and recover. I need to be able to add multiple worksheets to a given file before accessing it.

I have tried using different versions of `openpyxl` and adding the command `"options={'in_memory': True}"` without success. When I remove the append requirement, the file that is created opens without issue, even if it is overwriting an old file.

I am using python version 3.7.9 and XlsxWriter version 1.3.7, along with openpyxl 3.0.5 and pandas 1.2.0.

Thank you for looking!

```
import pandas as pd

dfOutput = pd.DataFrame(['A', 'B'], [1, 2])

excel_ws = "ExistingSheet"
FileOut = r"C:\Users\c1yj83\Documents\ExcelCantera\AppendToExcel.xlsx"


with pd.ExcelWriter(FileOut, mode='a', engine='openpyxl') as writer:
    dfOutput.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=excel_ws+'-Results')
```

Comment: You cannot append to a file with xlsxwriter as a Pandas engine (or in general either). You will have to use openpyxl. Why that isn't currently working I don't know.

Comment: Thanks jmcnamara for looking. I wonder if it may have something to do with how the security for my computer or Excel is setup. My company does not allow me administrator rights.

Comment: Update: I was not able to figure out what the issue with append is. I ended up writing each python result to a separate Excel file, then used VB to copy them to the original file and delete each results file. Not ideal, but since I was activating the python code via Excel to begin with it worked out okay. Doesn't solve the issue for those not already in Excel.